# Prevent the download of Gradle and Maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

> Before asking my question I'd like to apologize if this is really a
>   simple question.

I'm trying to find out the way, where we can locate and reuse the dependencies of Gradle and Maven. I want to find the possibilities of reusing them within multiple projects at the same time, opened in STS, Eclipse or Intellij.

*Instead of download them every time when we create a new project. It will save me the data, time and disk space.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle, like Maven, has an *Offline Mode*, which means you're telling it to always try to re-use cached dependencies instead of resolving them from network.
Each of the dependency manager has a command line option for this, but in IntelliJ IDEA you can enable/disable it simply by toggling an icon-button in the Gradle toolbar.

[image]

And the same for Maven.

[image]

Comment: I actually just faced this problem. I created the same project twice and each time it downloaded around 100MB of data. According to you, if the second time I toggled it to offline mode. Then it wasn't downloaded them again? But I saw a notif which says the import settings when I toggled it actually, before asking this question.

Comment: @LetMeCodeYou if you toggle offline mode on, it won't download anything from the network. Toggle it, and then import.

Comment: I wonder what else I need to do other than this offline mode. As I just created a new project and copied the same build.gradle file and was assuming that it will not go for the download. But that's not the case. Where I can mention and let the intellij know to look for the gradle and its dependencies? Instead of downloading every time I create a new project.

Comment: @LetMeCodeYou oh btw, it might be you see a sort of "download progress", but it's not using the network at all.

Comment: It's actually start downloading. May be I need to monitor the data usage.

Comment: I confirmed, its using data. And it is in offline mode too. Can't we specify to look for specific directories when you need these dependencies. And only download those which are not available.

Comment: @LetMeCodeYou it's strange, I've just tried here and no network is used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210288/discussion-between-letmecodeyou-and-lppedd).

Answer (score 3):

Maven dependencies are *not* downloaded again every time you create a new project.

They are downloaded to the local repository of your computer *once* and then they are read from there. So as long as you open a new project on the same account, Maven does not redownload dependencies.

The exception are SNAPSHOT dependencies, for which Maven periodically looks for new updates in the remote repositories.